# Recursive find and replace of attribute names on a nested Python object

Tags: python

A third party has provided me with a data structure that's a bunch of nested Python objects. It is strictly a tree. Some of the attribute names on these objects are Python reserved words such that attempting to access them results in a SyntaxError:

```
 >>> print mat['model'].rules[8].def.blocklabel
   File "<stdin>", line 1
     print mat['model'].rules[8].def.blocklabel
                              ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here the interpreter complains about the use of "def" as an attribute name. I'd like to recursively search the data structure and change any offending attribute names. What's the easiest way to do it? Tightest recipe wins!

Cheers!

Comment: What is your starting point?  Can you provide a sample of the data you start with so we can see how the *def* attribute got created to begin with?  Right now, it is not clear what tree needs to be walked.

Comment: The data were imported using scipy.io.loadmat(...). I should think that there's probably a way of doing this that's agnostic to the data, though. Points awarded for generality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the not-very-general answer for those of you who, like me, are dealing with scipy.io.loadmat() and just want to move on with your day:

```
from scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params import mat_struct as matlab_struct
def recursive_rename( obj,oldattr,newattr ) :        
    if isinstance(obj,matlab_struct) :
        for attr in obj._fieldnames :
            tmp = getattr(obj,attr)
            recursive_rename( tmp, oldattr, newattr )
            if attr == oldattr :
                setattr( obj, newattr, tmp )
                delattr( obj, oldattr )
                obj._fieldnames.remove( oldattr )
                obj._fieldnames.append( newattr )
    elif isinstance(obj,numpy.ndarray) and obj.dtype == object :
        iter = itertools.product(*[xrange(z) for z in obj.shape])  
        for i in iter : recursive_rename(obj[i], oldattr, newattr )
    else : pass
```

No points for me!